# java mysql load data local infile return errors

Tags: java, mysql

I'm currently trying to load a csv file into MySQL database via entity manager.

Please see code below:

```
public void CsvLoad(String name, Environment env) throws SQLException {

    int r = getEntityManager(env).createNativeQuery("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + name + "' INTO TABLE  gabstar.tblladetails FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  IGNORE 1 LINES (@UPRN,  @Address,   @PostCode,  @Lat_Long,  @region,    @Scheme,    @Estate,    @LocalAuthority,    @Bedrooms,  @PropertyType,  @AssetType, @TenureType, @HousingOffice,    @EmptyDays, @Date,  @Month, @Year,  @GrantLiability,    @RentperWeek,   @BookValue, @BudgetIncome,  @BudgetVoids,   @BudgetMajorRepair, @BudgetMaintenance, @BudgetServiceCharge,   @BudgetBadDebt, @BudgetManagementCost) \n" +
            "SET ID = NULL, \n" +
            "UPRN = @UPRN, Address = @Address,  PostCode = @PostCode,   Lat_Long = @Lat_Long,   region = @region,   Scheme = @Scheme,   LocalAuthority = @LocalAuthority,   Bedrooms = @Bedrooms,   PropertyType = @PropertyType,   AssetType = @AssetType, TenureType = @TenureType,HousingOfficer = @HousingOfficer,  EmptyDays = @EmptyDays, Date = @Date,   Month = @Month, Year = @Year,   GrantLiability = @GrantLiability,   RentperWeek = @RentperWeek, BookValue = @BookValue, BudgetIncome = @BudgetIncome,   BudgetVoids = @BudgetVoids, BudgetMajorRepair = @BudgetMajorRepair, BudgetMaintenance = @BudgetMaintenance, BudgetServiceCharge = @BudgetServiceCharge, BudgetBadDebt = @BudgetBadDebt, BudgetManagementCosts = @BudgetManagementCosts"
    ).executeUpdate() ;

}
```

Now the issue I have is I'm trying to return error messages that come from the file but it does create any exception even though I know the CSV file is incorrect.

How can I do this?

I basically would like the error message that you get with MySQL workbench.